# Numpy float promotion inconsistency

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, casting

It is my understanding that in `x = f() * g()`, first `f()` executes, then `g()`, then results are multiplied, and only then assigned to `x`. Yet below seems to contradict this:

```py
import numpy as np

print(np.sqrt(2).dtype)
print((np.array([1.], dtype='float32') * np.array([.5], dtype='float64')).dtype)
print((np.array([1.], dtype='float32') * np.sqrt(2)).dtype)
```

```py
>>> float64
>>> float64
>>> float32
```

In all my prior experience, Numpy promoted to the greater `dtype`, but not here. Same behavior if we assign individual arrays and multiply afterwards. I imagine Numpy uses some hidden attribute besides `dtype` rather than overruling Python execution.

How's it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2nd line:

```
print((np.array([1.], dtype='float32') * np.array([.5], dtype='float64')).dtype)
```

you are multiplying two arrays and hence it promotes the dtype (as you expect). However, in third line:

```
print((np.array([1.], dtype='float32') * np.sqrt(2)).dtype)
```

You are multiplying a scalar into an array and it preserves the array dtype. Note that if instead you replace the scalar with an array like this:

```
print((np.array([1.], dtype='float32') * np.sqrt([2])).dtype)
```

You will get `float64` as you expect again.

Comment: I see, so array `dtype` always takes precedence over scalar (0-dim) `dtype`?

Comment: Yes, [it does](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type): _"When both scalars and arrays are used, the array’s type takes precedence"_

Comment: Note that **numba** `@njit` does not follow this convention.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Thank you for the note. That is an interesting detail.

Comment: In fact Python floats will also force promotion to `float64`, even if every other scalar and ndim array is `float32`, like `2. * x`... would rather it stuck to Numpy's rules.